# open repair option of msoffice 2013 using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm try to automating the below manual steps for Micorsoft office 2013 using vbscript. 
1. Open Control panel.
2 .Select Ms foccice 2013 
3. Right click -- > select change option
4. Select "Repair " option

I am able to open control panel but how can i perform step 3 and step 4.

Anybody with vbscript experience please help to resolve.

Thanks
Jerk

Comment: Please post whatever code you have tried till now. I am not able to understand much of your question. May be I will understand once the code is posted.

Comment: i have opened application wizard using below line of code. I don't how to proceed further.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "control.exe appwiz.cpl"

Comment: Not well versed with what you are trying to do but you can try this link that I found from google.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692648.aspx

Comment: I cannot find any helpful links over there. My intention is to automate the  steps in my question.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the WMI Win32_Product class, to find the installer MSI - and then using msiexec.exe /f with the correct switches to repair the product. This should be enough to get you started.